# How to save changes made in json file in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new on react and typescript so it's practice project.
in which I am saving username and password in json file.
and added two static user details.
now when I am registering new user manipulate the file. and let me login with that same username and password.
but when I refresh page that user details get lost. **[Means file is not getting saved after manipulation ]**

FILE : APP.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './login';
import Register from './register';
import List from './list';


class Authenticate extends React.Component<any,any>{
  constructor(props:any){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      newUser:false,
      displayButtonText:"New On This Portal..!",
      displayForm:true,
      userList:''
    }
  }

  changeButton=()=>{
    var userType:Boolean=!this.state.newUser;
    var buttonText:String=(userType)?"Existing User..!" : "New On This Protal..!"
    this.setState({newUser:userType,displayButtonText:buttonText})
  }

  chnageUserType=()=>{
    this.changeButton();  
    this.setState({
      newUser:true
    })
  }

  getUsers=()=>{
    const provider={
        method:'GET',
        header:{'Content-Type':'Application/json'}
    }

    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",provider)
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=> this.setState({ userList: data.data,displayForm:false }));   
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="main">
        {
            (!this.state.displayForm)?
                <div>
                    <h2 style={{marginBottom:"none !important"}}>This is the list of people Registered on my Protal</h2>
                    <List Content={this.state.userList} />
                </div>
            :
            <div>
                <h2 style={{marginBottom:"none !important"}}>Welcome To My Testing Portal </h2>
                {(this.state.newUser)?<Register />:<Login UserManager={this.chnageUserType} showUserList={this.getUsers}/>}
                <button className="newButton" onClick={this.changeButton}><u>{this.state.displayButtonText}</u></button>
            </div>
        }      
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Authenticate;
```

File login.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import InputBox from './inputBox';
import Users from './users.json'
import Labels from './labels';
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert';
import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css';

class Login extends React.Component<any,any>{

    constructor(props:any){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            username:'',
            password:'',
            users:Users,
            errors:{
                value:false,
                errorMessage:''
            },
            userList:{}
        }
    }

    //API PRACTICE WITH FETCH
    componentDidMount=()=>{
        var data={
            method:'GET',
            header:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        }
        fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",data)
        .then(Response => Response.json())
        .then(data=>this.setState({userList:data.data}));

    }

    login = (event:any) =>{        
        event.preventDefault();         
        if(this.state.username==='')
        {
            this.setState({
                errors:{
                    value:true,
                    errorMessage:"Username field can't be empty..!"
                }
            })
        }
        else if(this.state.password===''){
            this.setState({
                errors:{
                    value:true,
                    errorMessage:"Password field can't be empty"
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            if(this.checkUser(this.state.username,this.state.password)){
                (this.checkUser(this.state.username,this.state.password))?alert("Welcome "+ this.state.username) : alert("user not exist please register");
                this.viewList();
            }   
            else{
                alert("user not exist please register");
                this.props.UserManager();
            }
        }
    }

    viewList=()=>{
        confirmAlert({
            title: "Checkout users my list",
            message:"Do you want to check users on my portal",
            buttons:[
                {
                    label:"Yeah sure",
                    onClick:()=>this.props.showUserList()
                },
                {
                    label:"Not really",
                    onClick:()=> alert("Alright Thank for visit. Comeback again")
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    checkUser=(username:string,password:string)=>{
        var i:number=0;

        while(i<Users.length){
            if(username===Users[i].username && password===Users[i].password)
                return true;            
            i+=1;
        }

        return false;
    }

    setValue=(event:any)=>{
       
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]:event.target.value,
            errors:{
                value:false,
                errorMessage:''
            }
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="authenticationBox">
                <h3 style={{marginTop:"none"}}>Login </h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.login} className="flexBoxColumn">
                    <InputBox Type="text" OnClick={this.setValue} Classes="inputBox" Name="username" PlaceHolder="Enter Username/Email"/>
                    <InputBox Type="password" OnClick={this.setValue} Classes="inputBox" Name="password" PlaceHolder="Enter Password" />
                    {this.state.errors.value ? <Labels labelName={this.state.errors.errorMessage}/> : null}
                    <InputBox Type="submit" Classes="submitButton inputBox" Value="Login"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login
```

File: Register.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'
import InputBox from './inputBox';
import Users from './users.json';
import Labels from './labels';


export default class Register extends React.Component<any,any>{
    constructor(props:any){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            username:'',
            password:'',
            cpassword:'',
            users:Users,
            errors:{
                value:false,
                errorMessage:''
            }
        }
    }

    registration = (event:any) =>{
        event.preventDefault();         
        if(this.state.username==='')
        {
            this.setState({
                errors:{
                    value:true,
                    errorMessage:"Username field can't be empty..!"
                }
            })
        }
        else if(this.state.password===''){
            this.setState({
                errors:{
                    value:true,
                    errorMessage:"Password field can't be empty"
                }
            })
        }
        else if(this.state.cpassword===''){
            this.setState({
                errors:{
                    value:true,
                    errorMessage:"Confirm Password field can't be empty..!"
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            if(this.state.password!==this.state.cpassword)
                alert("Password and Confirm password must be Same");
            else{
                var fs=require("browserify-fs");
                var user={username:this.state.username,password:this.state.password}
                Users.push(user);
                console.log(Users);
                var TempUsers=JSON.stringify(Users);

                fs.writeFile('./users.json', TempUsers, function() {
                    fs.readFile('./users.json', 'utf-8', function(err:any, data:any) {
                        console.log("aaaB "+data);
                    });
                });

                // console.log(TempUsers);
                // fs.writeFile("./users.json", TempUsers,function(err:any) {
                //     if (err) throw err;
                //     console.log('complete');
                // });
            }
        }
    }

    valueChange = (event:any)=>{
        this.setState({
            errors:{
                value:false,
                errorMessage:''
            }
        })
        if(event.target.name==="username"){  
            this.checkExistingUser(event.target.value,this.state.users);
        }
        else{
            this.checkExistingUser(this.state.username,this.state.users);
        }
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
    }

    checkExistingUser=(inputedUsername:string,existingUserNames:any)=>{
        console.log(inputedUsername);   
        var i:number=0;
        while(i<existingUserNames.length){
            if(inputedUsername===existingUserNames[i].username){
                this.setState({
                    errors:{
                        value:true,
                        errorMessage:"Username already exist..!"
                    }
                })
                break;
            }else{
                this.setState({
                    errors:{
                        value:false,
                        errorMessage:''
                    }
                })
            }
            i+=1;
        }
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="authenticationBox">    
                <h3 style={{marginTop:"none"}}>Register</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.registration} className="flexBoxColumn">
                    <InputBox Type="text" Classes="inputBox" Name="username" OnClick={this.valueChange} PlaceHolder="Enter Username/Email"/>
                    <InputBox Type="password" Classes="inputBox" Name="password" OnClick={this.valueChange} PlaceHolder="Enter Password" />
                    <InputBox Type="password" Name="cpassword" Classes="inputBox" OnClick={this.valueChange} PlaceHolder="Re-enter Password" />
                    {this.state.errors.value ? <Labels labelName={this.state.errors.errorMessage}/> : null}
                    <InputBox Type="submit" Value="Register" Classes="submitButton inputBox" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

File: users.json

```
[ 
    {  
      "username": "Dinesh0098",  
      "password": "123456"
    }, 
    { 
       "username": "worriormp", 
       "password": "qwertyuiop"
    } 
]
```

OUPUT on console when I register

```
[{"username":"Dinesh0098","password":"123456"},{"username":"worriormp","password":"qwertyuiop"},{"username":"Dinesh","password":"123"}]
```

Comment: Try to catch errors in `fs.writeFile('./users.json', TempUsers, function(err:any, data:any)`

Comment: @RahulBhobe I have added a catch block [ fs.writeFile('./users.json', TempUsers, function() {
                    fs.readFile('./users.json', 'utf-8', function(err:any, data:any) {
                        
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                },**function(err:any){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    console.log("aaaaaaaaaa");
                });** ] but console output is still same and and problem is still same

Comment: you have added this on `read()` function. Do this in `write()` function?

Comment: @RahulBhobeIf you check it carefully I have added this after read() scope get over.